# How to retrieve the String from MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I am using MultiAutoCompleteTextView , i want to append selected text in MultiAutoCompleteTextView, 
i m trying

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) arg0
                    .getItemAtPosition(arg2);


            String name = map.get("Name");
            String number = map.get("Phone");
            automulti.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());


            Log.d("ad:", automulti.getText().toString());
            automulti.append(", " + name  );




        }
```

Comment: And what is going wrong

Comment: it append all inforomation  `abc{Name=abc,Phone=232}`, i want append onle name

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your Map, not the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 MultiAutoCompleteTextView myEditText = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.mymulti);
   String stringEditText = myEditText.getText().toString();
```